# How to convert this nested loop to numpy broadcast?

Tags: numpy

I want to rearrange my data (two even-length 1d arrays):

```py
cs = [w x y z]
rs = [a b c d e f]
```

to make a result like this:

```py
[[a b w x]
 [c d w x]
 [e f w x]
 [a b y z]
 [c d y z]
 [e f y z]]
```

This is what I have tried (it works):

```py
ls = []
for c in range(0,len(cs),2):
  for r in range(0,len(rs),2):
    item = [rs[r], rs[r+1], cs[c], cs[c+1]]
    ls.append(item)
```

But I want to get the same result using reshaping/broadcasting or other numpy functions.
What is the idiomatic way to do this task in numpy?

Comment: A good start would be to reshape the arrays to (3,2) and (2,2).  That will make it easier to visualize how to use `np.repeat` or `tile` to build the larger blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could tile the elements of `rs`, repeat the elements of `cs` and then arrange those as columns for a 2D array:

```py
import numpy as np

cs = np.array(['w', 'x', 'y', 'z'])
rs = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])
res = np.c_[np.tile(rs[::2], len(cs) // 2), np.tile(rs[1::2], len(cs) // 2),
            np.repeat(cs[::2], len(rs) // 2), np.repeat(cs[1::2], len(rs) // 2)]
```

Result:

```py
array([['a', 'b', 'w', 'x'],
       ['c', 'd', 'w', 'x'],
       ['e', 'f', 'w', 'x'],
       ['a', 'b', 'y', 'z'],
       ['c', 'd', 'y', 'z'],
       ['e', 'f', 'y', 'z']], dtype='<U1')
```

An alternative:

```py
np.c_[np.tile(rs.reshape(-1, 2), (len(cs) // 2, 1)),
      np.repeat(cs.reshape(-1, 2), len(rs) // 2, axis=0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using `tile/repeat`, is to generate repeated row indices.

Make the two arrays - reshaped as they will be combined:

```
In [106]: rs=np.reshape(list('abcdef'),(3,2))
In [107]: cs=np.reshape(list('wxyz'),(2,2))
In [108]: rs
Out[108]: 
array([['a', 'b'],
       ['c', 'd'],
       ['e', 'f']], dtype='<U1')
In [109]: cs
Out[109]: 
array([['w', 'x'],
       ['y', 'z']], dtype='<U1')
```

Make 'meshgrid' like indices (`itertools.product` could also be used)

```
In [110]: IJ = np.indices((3,2))
In [111]: IJ
Out[111]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [2, 2]],

       [[0, 1],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 1]]])
```

`reshape` with `order` gives two 1d arrays:

```
In [112]: I,J=IJ.reshape(2,6,order='F')
In [113]: I,J
Out[113]: (array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]), array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]))
```

Then just index the `rs` and `cs` and combine them with `hstack`:

```
In [114]: np.hstack((rs[I],cs[J]))
Out[114]: 
array([['a', 'b', 'w', 'x'],
       ['c', 'd', 'w', 'x'],
       ['e', 'f', 'w', 'x'],
       ['a', 'b', 'y', 'z'],
       ['c', 'd', 'y', 'z'],
       ['e', 'f', 'y', 'z']], dtype='<U1')
```

### edit

Here's another way of looking this - a bit more advanced.  With sliding_window_view we can get a "block" view of that `Out[114]` result:

```
In [130]: np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(_114,(3,2))[::3,::2,:,:]
Out[130]: 
array([[[['a', 'b'],
         ['c', 'd'],
         ['e', 'f']],

        [['w', 'x'],
         ['w', 'x'],
         ['w', 'x']]],


       [[['a', 'b'],
         ['c', 'd'],
         ['e', 'f']],

        [['y', 'z'],
         ['y', 'z'],
         ['y', 'z']]]], dtype='<U1')
```

With a bit more reverse engineering, I find I can create Out[114] with:

```
In [147]: res = np.zeros((6,4),'U1')
In [148]: res1 = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(res,(3,2),writeable=True)[::3,::2,:,:]
In [149]: res1[:,0,:,:] = rs
In [150]: res1[:,1,:,:] = cs[:,None,:]
In [151]: res
Out[151]: 
array([['a', 'b', 'w', 'x'],
       ['c', 'd', 'w', 'x'],
       ['e', 'f', 'w', 'x'],
       ['a', 'b', 'y', 'z'],
       ['c', 'd', 'y', 'z'],
       ['e', 'f', 'y', 'z']], dtype='<U1')
```

I can't say that either of these is superior, but they show there are various ways of "vectorizing" this kind of array layout.